# How to disable auto login redirect in Spring Boot Keycloak Adapter

Tags: spring-boot, http, security, keycloak, http-status-code-403

I am writing an API in Spring Boot that I want to secure using Keycloak.
After doing some setting up, I managed to get the keycloak adapter to work. While I was expecting a 403 on any non-authenticated request, I get an HTTP 302 redirect to login page instead.
As I am working on an API, how can I disable the auto login-redirect and provide a 403 error message, so that I could add some frontend logic to start on the login process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your config, you do

```
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())
```

It will start returning 403 on every failed call and you can then catch it and whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the propery keycloak.bearer-only: true in the application.properties or application.yml to avoid redirect to login page when there is one error
You will get one 401 error